# Undesired button resizing after being transformed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create an expandable/collapsible menu for a personal project of mine. I have everything almost where I want it (in terms of it being behaving as expected anyway). When I collapse my menu, I want the buttons to rotate to a vertical position and *not* resize (Or at least resize to something that still fits the text). At the moment, the buttons rotate, then shrink vertically (what was/is the width) along with the parent control, which cuts off much of the contents. I can see why this would happen, but I can't think of a way around it that seems right to me.

Here is the behavior I'm seeing:
Before: [image: Before] After: [image: After]

As you can see, the buttons are shrinking along their now-vertical width (to what I assume would be the width of the enclosing `StackPanel`).

**Here is the code I am using:**

ExpaningMenu.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Budgety.Controls.ExpandingMenu"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Budgety.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         Name="MainExpandingMenu"
         MinWidth="32"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="100"> 
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Name="MenuPanel" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="{DynamicResource BackColor}" Grid.Row="1">
        <!--Contents will go here-->
    </StackPanel>
    <Button Name="StateToggle" Width="100" Height="32" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Panel.ZIndex="1" Background="{DynamicResource BackColor}" BorderThickness="0" Click="Button_Click" Content="&#171;"></Button>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ExpandingMenu.xaml.cs

```
public partial class ExpandingMenu : UserControl
{
    public ExpandingMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //For testing purposes.
        MenuPanel.Children.Add(new ExpandingMenuButton("TEST ITEM 1"));
        MenuPanel.Children.Add(new ExpandingMenuButton("TEST ITEM 2"));
        MenuPanel.Children.Add(new ExpandingMenuButton("TEST ITEM 3"));
        MenuPanel.Children.Add(new ExpandingMenuButton("TEST ITEM 4"));
        MenuPanel.Children.Add(new ExpandingMenuButton("TEST ITEM 5xxx"));

        foreach (UIElement element in MenuPanel.Children)
        {
            (element as ExpandingMenuButton).HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        }
    }

    #region Events
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MenuPanel.Width == 100) //Need to collapse
        {
            StateToggle.Width = MenuPanel.Width = 32;

            (sender as Button).Content = "\u00BB";

            //Flip all children of this control (so far, assuming only ExpandingMenuButtons)
            foreach (UIElement element in MenuPanel.Children)
            {
                (element as ExpandingMenuButton).LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform(-90);

                //This works to resize to 100 tall (not ideal...)
                //(element as ExpandingMenuButton).Width = 100;
                //This does not seem to size to auto, which SHOULD make each button as long as the text requires... (this behavior is far less than ideal...)
                //(element as ExpandingMenuButton).Width = Double.NaN;
            }
        }
        else //Need to expand
        {
            StateToggle.Width = MenuPanel.Width = 100;
            (sender as Button).Content = "\u00AB";

            //Flip all children of this control (so far, assuming only ExpandingMenuButtons)
            foreach (UIElement element in MenuPanel.Children)
            {
                (element as ExpandingMenuButton).LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform(0);
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

ExpandingMenuButton.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Budgety.Controls.ExpandingMenuButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Budgety.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="100"
         Height="30"
         Name="ButtonControl">
<Grid Name="ButtonGrid" Height="30">
    <ToggleButton Name="MenuButton" Background="Aqua" BorderThickness="1" Content="TEST"></ToggleButton>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ExpandingMenuButton.xaml.cs

```
public partial class ExpandingMenuButton : UserControl
{
    //Will definitely want custom functionalty here. TBD. Nothing special so far.

    #region Constructors
    public ExpandingMenuButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ExpandingMenuButton(string sText)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MenuButton.Content = sText;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

If you'd like to test the code out, it should work placed in a normal grid as I have (The above mentioned UserControls I've made are in a Controls folder within the project):

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Budgety"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Budgety.Controls" x:Class="Budgety.MainTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainTest" Height="600" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Controls:ExpandingMenu x:Name="ExpandingMenu" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**After all is said and done, here is the behavior/look I am after** (notice buttons are not shortened)[image: Desired look]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the layout you're seeing is the fixed height constraint you placed in `ExpandingMenuButton`: `Height="30"` on both the `UserControl` and the `Grid` element. You can change it to `MinHeight`.

In addition, when you set the **width** of the `MenuPanel`, you're also containing the **height** of the buttons, because you apply a transform.

Here's one way to fix this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (StateToggle.IsChecked == true)
    {
        StateToggle.Content = "\u00BB";
        foreach (FrameworkElement element in MenuPanel.Children)
            element.LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform(-90);
    }
    else
    {
        StateToggle.Content = "\u00AB";
        foreach (FrameworkElement element in MenuPanel.Children)
            element.LayoutTransform = null;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Name="MenuPanel"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Background="{DynamicResource BackColor}"
                Grid.Row="1">
        <!--Contents will go here-->
    </StackPanel>
    <ToggleButton Name="StateToggle"
                  FontSize="18"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Panel.ZIndex="1"
                  Background="{DynamicResource BackColor}"
                  BorderThickness="0"
                  Click="Button_Click"
                  Content="&#171;" />
</Grid>
```

As a general rule, don't specify widths and heights in WPF - let the layout system do the measuring for you according to the content.

Comment: I changed `Height` to `MinHeight` on the `ExpandingMenuButton` `UserControl` and added it in the `StackPanel` of the `ExpandingMenu`, but the behavior is the same. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: This still does not seem to affect the way it looks. See my edit for a screenshot of what I'm after in case I didn't describe something clearly enough.

Comment: Your above solution seems to work pretty well, but is there a way to make them stack from the top down? The `ExpandingMenuButton`s seem to start at the bottom and stack upward.

Comment: Yeah, coming from WinForms it's definitely not easy. I have a book shipping, but am trying to get as much out of this as possible by playing with it. At least I feel like I'm close... Just this one issue.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, that sure is interesting :) Guess the rest of my evening will be reading through this code and understanding what it's doing! Thanks again!

Comment: I agree. I can see the power for sure. It's just so... tempting to try to use absolutes like with WinForms. I'll definitely follow your advice and give myself a reality check if I catch myself doing it! not to mention my instinct was to calculate a solution to individual button widths... gross. but at least I had the common sense to know that was wrong and come here for help!